# How do you dynamically include a module based on what modules are available?

Tags: perl, module, include, require, moose

I have a perl script that uses the CGI::Session::Drive::memcached, but I want to be able to fallback on the default Session driver or another driver if it's available on the system...

This is how I started off using Memcache, but this doesnt necessarily solve the problem of the case when Cache::Memecached and/or CGI::Session::Driver::memcached are not available...

```
package MySession;

use Moose::Role;
use Moose::Util::TypeConstraints; 
use namespace::autoclean;

use CGI::Session ('-ip_match');
use CGI::Session::Driver::memcached;
use Cache::Memcached::Fast;

#would be nice to create this conditionally, or use a delegate maybe
has 'memeCached' => (
 is        => 'rw', 
 isa       => 'Maybe[Cache::Memcached::Fast]', 
 default => sub{ return Cache::Memcached::Fast->new( {'servers' => [ '10.x.x.x.:10001' ],'compress_threshold' => '100000','nowait' => 1,'utf8' => 1} ) },

);


  sub buildSession{
    my($this,$cgi,$sessionDir) = @_;

    $cgi = $cgi || $this->getCGI();

    my $sid = $this->SID();        
    my $mem = $this->memeCached(); 

    my $sss;

    if(!$mem){
        $sss = CGI::Session->load(undef, $cgi, {Directory=>$sessionDir}) or die CGI::Session->errstr();
    }else{
            $sss = CGI::Session->load( "driver:memcached", $cgi, { Memcached => $mem }) or die CGI::Session->errstr();
    }

...
```

Then this got me thinking, how do I do this -- in a general sense? or what's the best way to do this (especially using Moose)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had a similar situation. We use Windows domains, which I can connect to Net::LDAP. In my program, I want to be able to take the user ID `jsmith`, and instead of printing on the user ID, I want to be able to print out the name `John Smith`.

Many people at my company use my program, but not all are Perl experts and most wouldn't know how to install a Perl module. And, since Net::LDAP is not a standard module, many people don't have it.

Instead, I wanted a fallback routine. If I could look up the name with `Net::LDAP`, I would print the name, if I couldn't load `Net::LDAP`, I would fallback and just print the user ID.

I used the following for testing if `Net::LDAP` was installed, and load it if possible:

```
BEGIN {
    eval { require Net::LDAP; };
    our $Net_Ldap_Status  = 1 if (not $@);
}
```

What you have to understand is that:

```
use Foo::Bar;
```

is the same as:

```
BEGIN {
    require Foo::Bar;
}
```

It loads in the module at *compile* time. By surrounding the `require` with an `eval` I can test whether the statement succeeds (and the module is loaded) or fails (the module doesn't load, but the program doesn't crash either.) I can then check `$@` to see if the module loaded or not. `$@` is the error message that eval sets. If `$@` is null, then the module exists and was loaded successfully.

I need to use a package variable (the `our $Net_Ldap_Status` instead of `my $Net_Ldap_Status`) or the variable will be lost when the program runs. (I'm not even sure if `my $Net_Ldap_Status` would work in a `BEGIN` statement).

Now, here's where things get funky...

When I need to check `$Net_Ldap_Status`, I need to redeclare it:

```
our $Net_Ldap_Status;
```

or I tend to get that non-declared variable error. The funny thing is that it doesn't lose its previous value by redeclaring it. Thus, somewhere in my code is:

```
our $Net_Ldap_Status;
if ($Net_Ldap_Status) {
   print "Code if Net::LDAP is loaded.\n";
}
else {
   print "Fallback Code if no Net::LDAP\n";
}
```

Comment: `use Foo::Bar;` is actually closer to `BEGIN { require Foo::Bar; import Foo::Bar; }`. But seeing as it's usually not useful to import conditionally, not calling `import` is probably a good idea.

Comment: are you using mod_perl? this might explain why redeclaring with our doesnt nuke the value. +1 for the anecdotal example

Comment: @ikegami True, if you look at [use](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/use.html) in Perldoc, it does include importing. However, there's no importing of functions in object oriented modules like `Net::LDAP` and `CGI::Session::Driver::memcached`, so I left it out for simplicity (plus, I didn't do it in my example).

Comment: @nodebunny - Not using mod_perl. `$Net_Ldap_Status` is a package variable which means it is stored in the symbol table with its value. I had to _redeclare_ the variable because the compiler complained that Global Variable `$Net_Ldap_Status` required an explicit package name. I could have simply used `$main::$Net_Ldap_Status` and skipped the `our $Net_Ldap_Status;` again. Come to think of it, I'm not 100% sure why I just didn't do it that way.

Comment: thank you for sharing your experience here, I like the solution you came up with and I'll try to implement it to see if it works for me!

Comment: Or, since you're using Moose, just use Class::Load, which is a requirement: http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Class::Load